# How to fix a broken column in CSV file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a csv file lets say (`citycode.csv`) that contains 4 columns and more than 600 rows and it looks like this:

Example:

```
**City_Code   City_Name   County_Name  Village_Name**
CT01122-01 Pinar del Río    Antilla      Cabañas
CT01123-01    Havana       Betancourt   Niquero
CT01124-01..........
CT01126-01..............
CT01128-01...............
```

and so on so forth (more than 600 rows).

First I need to remove all the 4th character (CT0**1**122-01) in the first column (`City_Code`) needs to be dropped. Besides that, I also want to read the `citycode.csv` file and write out the fixed version of the file.

Comment: What have you tried to do this? That is, what code have you written and what exact issues are you facing?

Comment: Are you sure your csv is split with `-`?

Comment: No there is no - I put for to make list effect.

Comment: codes = csv.reader(open('city_code.csv', 'wb'))
lines = list(codes)


writer = csv.writer(open('city_code.csv', 'w'))
writer.writerows(lines)

That's what I have. I do not know how to change all the 4th character of the 1 column.

Comment: Start with a for loop over `lines`

Comment: I'm curious what happens when the city name is more characters than the distance between `City_Name---------County_Name`... Are there still dashes? Is the city truncated? What are you to do when a city contains a dash?

Comment: There is no dash. my mistake made everyone confused.

Comment: Copy and paste a few lines from the beginning of the `city_code.csv` file into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'd try

```
with open('city_code.csv', 'r') as f_src, open('city_code_fixed.csv', 'w') as f_trgt:
    f_trgt.write(f_src.readline())         # for transferring the header untouched
    for line in f_src:
        f_trgt.write(line[:3] + line[4:])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: How can I skip the first line(header)?. I noticed that this code deletes the header 4th character also.

Comment: If you read from one file and write to another you don`t exactly want to _skip_, but to copy the header line untouched. See my edit.

Comment: yeah thanks for the edit. I was looking for logic that how your edit works. One question: using csv.DictReader is the better way to do this process?

Comment: **_IMO_** not. For this task, every imported library would be unnecessary overhead. Of course, with `csv` you can have some things more convenient, especially if you need more control with regards to the structure of your csv-file. And the same is true for `pandas`. But just iterating over the lines and kicking out one character...